# I would like my logo to make one full rotation as you scroll to the bottom of the page. How?

Tags: javascript, scroll, rotation, onscroll

My current code makes my logo rotate on scroll, but it makes more than one full rotation. How do I make it rotate only once throughout the entire page scroll?

P.S. Obviously, page height will vary; 10000px is for demo purposes only. Also, I divided window.pageYOffset by 10 to slow down rotation speed a little.

```js
var logo = document.getElementById("logo");
window.addEventListener("scroll", function() {
    logo.style.transform = "rotate("+window.pageYOffset/10+"deg)";
});
```

```css
.main {
    height:10000px;
}

#logo {
    position:fixed;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
    <div id="logo">
        <img src="https://files.cargocollective.com/c100310/test.svg" alt>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `360 * window.pageYOffset / (document.documentElement.scrollHeight - document.documentElement.clientHeight)` to calculate the angle

```js
var logo = document.getElementById("logo");
window.addEventListener("scroll", function() {
    logo.style.transform = "rotate("+(360 * window.pageYOffset / (document.documentElement.scrollHeight - document.documentElement.clientHeight))+"deg)";
});
```

```css
.main {
    height:10000px;
}

#logo {
    position:fixed;
    transition: transform 1s;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
    <div id="logo">
        <img src="https://files.cargocollective.com/c100310/test.svg" alt>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: sorry, I just posted a firefox only thing - damn, should look these things up

Comment: Sorry, but your code does not work. The logo doesn't rotate.

I tried in Chrome, Safari, and Edge on macOS.

Comment: it does work in firefox ONLY, so you tried everything but REAL firefox

Comment: @Alan - I've now replaced firefox only solution with one that should work everywhere (god I hope it does, thought the days of such inconsistencies was over)

Comment: Is it possible to add in-out easing to rotation?

Comment: probably - `transition: transform 1s;` seems to work